# Как подставить число из переменной в Rows

Tags: c#, datatable

Имеем `DataTable.Rows[0][0];`

Хотелось бы посдставлять значение строки из переменной. Это возможно?

Пример: `DataTable.Rows[Переменная][0]`.

Comment: то что вы показали - подстановка номера строки, да так можно, но число должно быть строго из диапазона номеров существующих строк. А вот что значит "посдставлять значение строки из переменной" - непонятно. Добавьте в вопрос пример кода, который вы хотели бы получить, но не получается и ожидаемый результат на выходе.

Answer (score 0):

Переменная может быть указана в квадратных скобках, как вы написали, в таком случае эта переменная выражает номер строки в двумерном массиве. Более того, в квадратных скобках может быть указано вообще любое выражение, результатом выполнения которого будет целое число int. Я сам не профессионал, но если такие вещи не очевидны для вас, настоятельно рекомендую прочесть любой  учебник по вашему языку программирования. Без знаний самых Азов, как следствие, будут непонятны другие обязательные к прочтению книги типа Джон Скит "C# для профессионалов. Тонкости программирования".